# How to avoid start the more then once process in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have trouble to find the root cause to solve the runaway process in my linux box, I installed tomcat my linux machine and inside that we have a project related war file to test our application, all the things are working fine as we expected.

But sometimes when we are checking java process i could see there  many running process instance on same machine as like below.

```
ps -ef | grep java
machine1  32947      1 20 Jan29 pts/1    12:21:28 //bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/sys/workspaces/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /sys/workspaces/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/sys/workspaces/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/sys/workspaces/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/sys/workspaces/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/sys/workspaces/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
machine1  56134  54750  0 04:57 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
machine1  83270      1  9 Jan03 ?        2-16:24:29 //bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/sys/workspaces/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /sys/workspaces/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/sys/workspaces/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/sys/workspaces/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/sys/workspaces/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/sys/workspaces/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
machine1  91202      1  8 Jan17 ?        1-05:09:36 //bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/sys/workspaces/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /sys/workspaces/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/sys/workspaces/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/sys/workspaces/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/sys/workspaces/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/sys/workspaces/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

can you please some help me on this.

Comment: Can you check if these processes running in the different ports?

Comment: Can you please me how to find that ?